# how to properly pass a pointer with the address of a variable from a function into another function that takes in a reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

The problem that I'm having is that my pointer that's declared in the main points to the address of a variable that is returned from a function, later I try to pass the pointer in a function that takes in a reference, but the value that it had is now gone and replaced by garbage values somehow. Please show me what I am doing wrong.

```
#include<iostream>

void  somthingwrong(int &x) //*takes in the pointers address* 
{
    std::cout << somfing << std::endl; //*supposed to print 5 but outputs a 
                                      // garbage value*
    return;
}

int& number()
{
    int g = 5;

    return g;
}

int main()
{   
    int *h = nullptr;  

    h = &number(); //*the pointer passed gets the value of 5*

    somthingwrong(*h); //*here in this function the value is somehow erased 
                       //and couts some garbage value*




    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You cannot return a reference to a local variable, so your `number` function is invalid.

Comment: why cant you??  the pointer h points to the address of g. I dont see why its illegal to do so.

Comment: This question was answered a few times already here on SO.

Comment: variable g does not exists after the number() is finished. So you cannot reference it anymore

Comment: hi my question has been answered, how do i flag it as answeredf

Comment: It is already flagged as a duplicate, you don't have to do anything. For the future, if you ask a question and it gets useful answers of its own (not a comment), you accept the best answer by clicking the V symbol on it.